# GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glfw, glew

I'm following the OpenGL tutorial at http://www.learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Hello-Window

I have the following code written as taught in the tutorial, however setting the profile causes an immediate segmentation fault. The program gives the expected output without that line.

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main() {
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); //SEGFAULT
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();
    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

If it helps, the output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` is below:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.1 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR` to `1`?  `glxinfo` seems to be telling that 3.1 is the specific core profile version.

Comment: @Keugyeol I'm not sure why it shows a different value for `version` and `core version` but if I set it to 3.1 it refuses to run at all. I'm quite sure that means my version is actually 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that core and compatibility profile modes were added in OpenGL 3.2. Since my system has 3.0, setting that parameter caused a crash.

So for versions lower than 3.2, you don't need to set compatibility mode or core profile.